# Swift Combine framework setFailureType error operator

Tags: swift, combine

For scientific reasons I've created a **Publisher** and a **Subscriber** so I can dive into Combine.

The **Publisher** has been converted from a **never failing** to the **failing** one.

```swift
enum IntegerError: String, Error {
    case miltupleOf2 = "We are sorry but the number is a multiple of 2, therefore cannot be used in the process"
}

let integerPublisher = [1,3,3,3,3,3,5,6,7,7].publisher
    .setFailureType(to: IntegerError.self)

let subscribtion = integerPublisher
    .tryMap { intValue in
        if intValue.isMultiple(of: 2) {
            throw IntegerError.miltupleOf2
        } else {
            return intValue
        }
    }
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("success")
        case .failure(let error):
            if let error = error as? IntegerError {
                print(error.rawValue)
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    }
```

My question is: when using **sink**, the error type is **Error**. Why is it not the custom **IntegerError** that I've used within the **.setFailureType** modifier?

The need of casting my error to the type that I specified earlier seems a little redundant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is quite straightforward. `tryMap` returns a [`Publishers.TryMap<Upstream, Output>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/trymap), which is a specific kind of publisher with [`Failure == Error`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/trymap/failure):

```
typealias Failure = Error
```

So as soon as you use `tryMap`, that undoes what `setFailureType` did.

The reason why `Publishers.TryMap` has `Error` as its `Failure` type is because in Swift, you can't specify what specific type of error a closure can throw (unlike Java for example). Once you mark a closure as `throws`, like `tryMap` has done with its `transform` parameter:

```
func tryMap<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) throws -> T) -> Publishers.TryMap<Self, T>
```

*any* `Error` can be thrown inside the `transform` closure. You can try changing `throw IntegerError.miltupleOf2` to throwing another type of error. Your code will still compile.

---

*Hypothetically*, if Swift allowed you to specify what type of error you are allowed to throw in the closure, then `tryMap` could have been declared as (fake syntax):

```
func tryMap<T, E: Error>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) throws E -> T) -> Publishers.TryMap<Self, T, E>
```

and you wouldn't even need `setFailureType`.

---

As a workaround, you can use `mapError` to cast the error to your desired type:

```
let subscribtion = integerPublisher
    .tryMap { intValue -> Int in
        if intValue.isMultiple(of: 2) {
            throw IntegerError.miltupleOf2
        } else {
            return intValue
        }
    }.mapError { $0 as! IntegerError }
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("success")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.rawValue)
        }
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    }
```

You need to reassure the compiler that you haven't thrown any other type of errors in `tryMap`.